# Send Row Data to Dialog Box for Editing

Tags: custom-actions, modal-dialog, query-string, custom-web-parts

I have created a custom ribbon button in SharePoint 2013 which enables when 2 or more files are selected and opens a dialog box. Within this dialog box, I would like to open a custom page which displays information from the selected files and allows the user to edit this information. Once the user has edited the information, I would like to consolidate the files and into one file with multiple versions. What I would like to know is how to send the data from the files selected to the web page in the dialog box as well as the best way to customize the web page in the dialog box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow the following blog post:
[SharePoint 2010: Get Selected Items from List View in Visual Web Part](http://arsalkhatri.wordpress.com/2012/12/01/sharepoint-2010-get-selected-items-from-list-view-in-visual-web-part/)

You can use this JavaScript on custom Ribbon Button and send the selected values to Dialog Box.. I am considering your dialog box will contain the Visual Web Part